# How can I track statistics regarding the number of sign-ups vs. account deletions?

Tags: nodes

I'm working on a social networking site in Drupal 7 that I haven't launched yet.  However, once I've launched I would like some basic metrics to track how I'm doing, particularly the number of sign-ups per week (or some other arbitrary interval) and the number of users who have cancelled/deleted their accounts.

Is there a way to track this from within Drupal?

Comment: Just a short thought: users do not necessarily delete accounts. They might just abandon them.

Comment: That's true, and it would be useful to track that as well.  However, my main concern is account deletion, because those users probably had an extremely bad experience at the site or have some other significant reason to leave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views is your friend. You can build a view that shows the total number of registrations per week, for example. You can use an exposed filter to change the date ranges.

You can use [user stats](http://drupal.org/project/user_stats) to keep track of last login time and then built a similar view.

If you user [userpoints](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints) you can get stats based on activity (or the lack thereof).

Answer (score 1):

First of all I wouldn't allow users to delete accounts themselves.

I would suggest to use [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) to gather requests for account deletion and additionally query users about the reason to delete account.

Then the site administrator would use a report based on Views Bulk Operations to delete accounts.

You can gather statistics based on urls used by users to register and to delete account.
See http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/statistics.

For more data analysis I use [Google Analytics](http://drupal.org/project/google_analytics).